I got TFS 2015 running in my company and http and ssh clone URLs are already setup, http URL is working for git clone but ssh URL is not working

`TFS 2015 is installed on Windows server 2019 Datacentre, Http URL is working fine for git clone,pull,push etc. But SSH URL is not working, giving below error.
"""
PS C:\Users\dkumar\Desktop\New folder> git clone "ssh://username@myServer:22/tfs/DefaultCollection/DevOpsTesting/DevOpsTesting Team/_git/DevOpsTesting"
Cloning into 'DevOpsTesting'...
username@server's password:
usage: git-upload-pack [--[no-]strict] [--timeout=] [--stateless-rpc]
[--advertise-refs] 
--[no-]stateless-rpc  quit after a single request/response exchange
--[no-]advertise-refs ...

alias of --http-backend-info-refs
--[no-]strict         do not try /.git/ if  is no Git directory
--[no-]timeout     interrupt transfer after  seconds of inactivity
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
"""
I tried restarting server, opening inbound outbound 22 ports and modifying TeamFoundationSshService.config file. And I tried to open TFS Administrator console which gave me another error with database.
error popup message
your text
I have opened port 22 and also modified TeamFoundationSshService.config file to-
Use nonConcurrent garbage collection -->




Other SSH service settings -->



`


Please let me know if you need more details.

the ssh url is not correct, you should copy the url when you clone the DevOps repo. please check the details below, thanks.

I can reproduce similar error on my side:

The ssh url in your command is not correct, there's an extra DevOpsTesting Team inside the url.
Please get the correct ssh url when you clone the repo.

Also make sure you have generated ssh keys on the agent, and add public keys to the TFS so that it can authenticate. More details on the official doc: Use SSH key authentication

Regarding the connection between console to database, it could be a different issue. It's recommended to:

Ping to database server, make sure it can be reached.
On database server, check the instance is running.
Ensure that the database instance specified in the TFS configuration is correct.

Hope it helps.
